# T-SQL: How to select one column or in alternative another one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to do a query and get a date from one column if it is not null, alternatives from a second column.

For example, my table is

```
Date1         Date2        AnotherColumn
01-01-2012    02-01-2012      ABC
NULL          02-01-2012      CDE
03-01-2012    05-01-2012      XZY
```

My query has to return `Date1` if `Date1` is not null, otherwise `Date2`.

Query result:

```
   Date         AnotherColumn
   01-01-2012     ABC
   02-01-2012     CDE
   03-01-2012     XYZ
```

How can do this in T-SQL ?

Comment: What have you tried? What does your table look like? What is your current query???

Comment: `COALESCE(field1, field2)` or `ISNULL(field1, field2)` or `CASE WHEN NOT field1 IS NULL THEN field1 ELSE field2 END`

Comment: `ISNULL(Field1, Field2)` OR `COALESCE(Field1, Field2, Field3)`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The details depend on your RDBMS, but many engines offer some kind of a [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function.

Here is how you do it in SQL Server:

```
select COALESCE(t.Date1, t.Date2) as Date
from MyTable t
```

When a coalesce function is not available, you can use a conditional expression. Here is the syntax for SQL Server:

```
select case
    when t.Date1 is not null then t.Date1
    else t.Date2
end as Date
from MyTable t
```

Comment: I like the `"case when ... else ... end as ..."` thing! Works in 8.x oracle.

Answer (score 3):

```
ISNULL(datefield1, datefield2)
```

I hope it will work for you.